# Lucene 7.1 when updateDocument how can I tell it is add or update?

Tags: lucene

Does the API has some return value that tells if it is adding or updating?
Because I need to know, but If I use "query - update" process, the performance is down, should the API be changed to tell more info?

Comment: why you need to know that? as afar as i know lucene does not differentiate between update and insert, so each update is deep down a delete and insert.

Comment: Insert will be cheaper than update. In my use case, the documents to insert/update is in order, so when a doc is real insert not updated, it means docs after it are all need insert only. this will improve the performance.

Comment: i don't really get it ... lucene does not provide a real "update" possibility. If you "update" an entry in the index, lucene is always doing a delete and insert.

Comment: Well,  the reason I cannot explain well but I believe it's the same with why  **SQL**'s `update` `insert` should return the actually updated count. Hope you don't think no people using SQL cares about the return count value.